# I keep getting this crash report on Minecraft 1.13 whenever I load a world. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 6/08/18 5:18 PM
Description: mouseClicked event handler

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at cjs.a(SourceFile:433)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: cmn
Stacktrace:
    at cjs.a(SourceFile:433)
    at cfk.a(SourceFile:83)
    at cfk$$Lambda$774/849031967.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.callback(GLFWMouseButtonCallbackI.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWaitEventsTimeout(GLFW.java:3108)
    at cfs.a(SourceFile:320)
    at cfi.c(SourceFile:872)
    at cfi.a(SourceFile:392)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.13
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 15300784 bytes (14 MB) / 268435456 bytes (256 MB) up to 268435456 bytes (256 MB)
    JVM Flags: 10 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Xmx1G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -Xmx256M
    Launched Version: 1.13
    LWJGL: 3.1.6 build 14
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics GL version 4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.3574, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems Minecraft ran out of memory.
Edit your launcher profile and at the bottom, should be "Java Settings". In "JVM Arguments", change the value of RAM you are assigning:

*Example: "-Xmx1G" to "-Xmx2G". Just make sure you don't add RAM you don't have installed.*

It can also be that you don't have enough RAM installed on your PC.

Comment: The system should have 4 GB of RAM considering the age of the (very bad) CPU. I guess 1 Gig is enough, but OP runs Minecraft with only 256 MB of RAM due to a mistake in the arguments.

Comment: Did not scroll to see the entire text for arguments. Yes. Big mistake to parse 2 different values, one of them being way too low. I offered a more general response so it can be used for visitors which encounter this issue too.

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine :) I just wanted to point out the actual reason for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your JVM arguments.

*(...)  **-Xmx1G** -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M **-Xmx256M***

You have set your allocated RAM to 1 GB (which would be fine), but then override it again by setting it to 256 MB, which is way too low.

Go to the JVM arguments as described in the answer by Softability and remove the *-Xmx256M* from the list and you should be able to play again.